# C++ Slower than Python? How is this possible?

Tags: c++, python, performance

I compiled one of my first programs in C++. Then I ran it along side the identical program in Python (haven't figured out if statements in C++ yet). The Python program was double the speed. I was always under the impression C++ and other compiled languages were much faster. Here are the programs, perhaps I am doing something wrong.

```
def main():
    num1 = int(input('Enter an integer: '))
    num2 = int(input('Enter another integer: '))
    if num1 > num2:
        while num1 >= num2:
            print(num1)
            num1 -= 1
    else:
        while num2 >= num1:
            print(num2)
            num2 -=1
 main()
```

---

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    int num1 = 0, num2 = 0;
    std::cout << "Enter an integer: ";
    std::cin >> num1;
    std::cout << "Enter another integer: ";
    std::cin >> num2;
    std::cout << std::endl;
    while (num1 >= num2) {
        std::cout << num1 << std::endl;
        --num1;
    }
    system("pause>nul");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Replace `std::endl` with `'\n'`

Comment: How did you measure the time? How did you feed both with the input ?

Comment: @tom std::endl should NOT be replaced by '\n'.

Comment: It was just with a stop watch, the python program finished almost twice as fast. However I see the reason for this now. Thanks.

Comment: @AhmedMasud only if you really want to flush the stream every time

Comment: Er, are these even equivalent? I don't see an `if` in the C++ program. And you used a physical stopwatch? Terribly imprecise...Also, did you compile with optimization?

Comment: @user2164854 where are you getting your standard input from? Are you just typing it in while you are timing it with a stopwatch or having it redirected to a file?

Comment: He's just timing the while loop, after the input has been processed.

Comment: Try compiling with optimization turned on. It can make a huge difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because std::cout is an incredibly slow operation and causes any program to stall almost completely.. a real test would be to not print every loop, but to time how long it takes and only output the time at the end.

Comment: std::cout is not a slow operation, it's a buffered operation and the buffer doesn't get flushed synchronous to the execution of the program unless you std::cout.flush() it.

Comment: std::endl flushes the buffer though, which he is doing

Comment: calling std::endl automatically flushes the buffer, so that is already being done.  In any case, it is still a slow operation.

Comment: @Lochemage Agreed I would try something that does a numerical computation like finding a prime number to the nth degree then compare the results.

Comment: @BeenCoding2Long Yes, another great point.  Many languages have their own strengths and weaknesses depending on what operations you use.  So it's good to compare results using an array of different operations.